# css selector targeting a h tag inside a div inside a link

Tags: html, css

I'm sure I have done this before but I just can't get this working for me now. I have a 'button' structured like this:

```
<a class="linkclass" href="#">
    <div class="divclass">
        <h3>TITLE</h3>
    </div>
</a>
```

I want to use a:link and a:visited to style the h3 but can't seem to get the CSS right to target it specifically and overide other CSS affecting it.

Thanks!

Comment: the link should be the innermost element of your structure, (inside `<h3>`). Could we see your attempts in a fiddle?

Comment: Add the CSS that you've tried to the question

Answer (score 1):

Select like this:

```
a.linkclass > div.divclass > h3 { }
a.linkclass:hover > div.divclass > h3 { }
a.linkclass:visited > div.divclass > h3 { }
```

Remember, that *cascading* is important in CSS ... as in your selectors *specificity* must be greater for the `:hover`and `:visited` to override any previous set selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.g.

```
a:hover h3 {}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gL4b97x/)